# How to play multiple files on multiple Androids?

Tags: audio, streaming

I have three Android devices and I have three tracks: a bass track, a drum track and a vocals track.
What I want is to play each track on each device simultaneously, like, one Android plays the drum track, the second Android plays the bass track and the third Android plays the vocals track, all of them simultaneously.
I can also use a Windows PC to stream or remote control the devices.
I've used many apps like AirFoil or SoundWire, but I can only play one track at the time.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe a batch file with a few `adb` commands will do the trick. Unfortunately I do not know the commands for opening a sound file on a phone (and properly syncing them as well).

Comment: Have the tracks loaded in the device. Then use a music player in each of the device, load a particular song (it would start playing) and reset the song progress to beginning. When you're done doing this in all of your devices,  (as GiantTree noted) dispatch (for Android 4.4 or above) `adb shell media dispatch play` for all the devices. They would start playing the song. Alternatively, for other Android versions, find the music player's activity responsible for playing the song and pass the data (the song file) into them using `adb shell am start`.

Comment: Another thing you can do is make [tag:Tasker] or an other competent app to play the files at a particular time in the devices.  Have the devices synchronize their time setting with a global time server for better synchronization.